# What is the difference between the ViewContext.Writer and System.Web.Mvc.IView Render(...) Writer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

The MVC 5 [IView.Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iview.render%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method has the following signature:

```
void Render(
    ViewContext viewContext,
    TextWriter writer
)
```

Meanwhile, `ViewContext` also has the [Writer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext.writer%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) property:

```
public virtual TextWriter Writer { get; set; }
```

In the Render method, what is the difference between these two `TextWriter` instances? When should I use one vs the other when rendering the content of the `IView`?